# Simple glossaries one to one translation between languages

Tags: glossaries

I would like to create a document with two `glossaries` of the following kind:

> **German to English**
>
> Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie: *Probability theory*
>
> Dichte: *Density*
>
> **English to German**
>
> Probability theory: *Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie*
>
> Density: *Dichte*

For each word and its translation, I would like to have just one LaTeX`entries which is used by both`glossaries`. So something of the following kind:

```
\newentry
{
    english = Probability theory,
    german = Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie
}
\newentry
{
    english = Density,
    german = Dichte
}
```

I could not figure out a way to do that with the package `glossaries`, but I am not familiar with it.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A preliminary version:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nomain]{glossaries}

\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{0.6\textwidth}

\newglossary{german}{ggin}{gglo}{German to English}
\newglossary{english}{bgin}{bglo}{English to German}


\newglossarystyle{dict}{%
  \setglossarystyle{long}%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
  {\begin{longtable}{lp{\glsdescwidth}}}%
    {\end{longtable}}%
  %
  \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \glstarget{##1}{\bfseries \glossentryname{##1}:}% Name
    & \textbf{\glossentrydesc{##1}}  \tabularnewline
  }%
}

\newcommand{\newdictentry}[3]{%
  \newglossaryentry{#1ger}{%
    name={#2},%
    description={#3},%
    type=german%
  }%
  \newglossaryentry{#1eng}{%
    name={#3},%
    description={#2},%
    type=english%
  }%
}


\newdictentry{hund}{Hund}{Dog}
\newdictentry{ente}{Ente}{Duck} 
\newdictentry{katze}{Katze}{Cat}
\newdictentry{ameise}{Ameise}{Ant}
\newdictentry{papagei}{Papagei}{Parrot}



\makeglossaries
\begin{document}

\glsaddall

My nice dictionary

\setglossarystyle{dict}
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It is nice. But I have a problem with accents: for example \newdictentry{wurfel}{W\"{u}rfel}{Die} does not work out.

Comment: @GillesBonnet: Try `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `Würfel` then

Comment: @GillesBonnet: `\newdictentry{wurfel}{W\"urfel}{Die}` works too. I find `\"{u}` rather strange